# Sharing a Json Array with Cordova Social Sharing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to share a list of products with Cordova Social Sharing on whatsapp, facebook,etc.
I tried Stringfying it, i tried many things, but nothing seemed to work, the only thing it sent is always an "[]"

So here's my html button

```
    <button id="comp-list" ng-click="OtherShare()" class="button button-block button-success item-icon-left" >
            <i class="icon ion-share"></i>
            Share
    </button>
```

and this is the part responsible in my controller

```
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.products.length; i++){
  var prodValue = {price:$scope.products[i].price, quantity:$scope.products[i].quantity};
  prodValue.price= $scope.products[i].price;
  prodValue.quantity= $scope.products[i].quantity;
  $scope.shareList[$scope.products[i].name] = prodValue;
}
$scope.OtherShare=function(){
  window.plugins.socialsharing.share($scope.shareList, null, null, 'www.google.com');
};
```

So anyone know how should i share the array in "shareList" using this plugin?
Anything that could help me sharing the content of shareList on whatsapp is welcome! =)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to stringy the text while sharing via social media

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share(JSON.stringify($scope.shareList), null, null, 'www.google.com');
```